# org/openrewrite/maven/RewriteRunMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, openrewrite

I am using OpenRewrite on my project, in IntelliJ.

This is the maven configuration for the plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <activeRecipes>
            <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.migrate.UpgradeToJava11</recipe>
        </activeRecipes>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-migrate-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

When I run the `rewrite:run` task, both by console and IntelliJ, it gives me this error

> Execution default-cli of goal
> org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.8.1:run failed: Unable to
> load  the mojo 'run' in the plugin
> 'org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.8.1' due to an API
> incompatibility:
> org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
> org/openrewrite/maven/RewriteRunMojo : Unsupported major.minor version
> 52.0

I've tried to change Java version, but with no results. I cannot find the problem.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? OpenRewrite requires at least Java 8, and the message seems to indicate you're using a lower version, based on: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-4.html

Comment: I have tried compiling with java 8, same results

Comment: The unsupported version is for JDK 8 which means you are not using JDK 8  try to do this: `mvn --version`...

Comment: Impossible, doesn't works from intellij too.

Comment: You can execute the cli parts from Intellij as well. ..also you should be able to do that on plain command line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found it.

[image]

Clicking with right and selecting "Modify Run Configuration"...

[image]

Change the setting from here to Java 8 solves the problem.